# Lazy loading vs eager loading Sequelize

Tags: javascript, database, performance, sequelize.js

I would like to know if there are any advantages using any of them. For example, imagine you have a Student and a ContactInfo relation and they have a One to One relationship. Now, you want to load a student with the contactInfo. You could do both ways:

```
const student = await Student.findOne({
  where: {
    name: "Jack"
  }
});

const contactInfo = await student.getContactInfo();

//Send response to client
```

or

```
const student= await Student.findOne({
  where: {
    name: "Jack"
  },
  include: ContactInfo
});
//Send response to client
```

Will I gain some performance going for one of them?

Answer (score 2):

Lazy Loading will generate 2 queries; one for `findOne` and the other for `getContactInfo`. While eager loading will generate 1 query to fetch both records.

Lazy loading

> This can be especially useful if we may or may not need the ship, perhaps we want to fetch it conditionally, only in a few cases; this way we can save time and memory by only fetching it when necessary.

Ref: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#lazy-loading-example

So, if you know you always send contactInfo, use eager loading. If you conditionally want to send contactInfo, try lazy loading.